# ios 6 - Fire segue just after data has been loaded

Tags: ios, ios6, uitableview, afnetworking, segue

I have some data in TableView. What I want is to call services just after user tapped on row.
Main problem is that 'performToSegue' is calling first so there is no data to populate in tableView in destination controller.

How can I call segue just after data has been retrieved?

Thanks a lot for suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You'll need to delete the segue in the storyboard that you dragged from a cell to the next viewController.
- Next make a segue by dragging from the current controller to the next controller

[image]

Now in the `UITableViewController` implement

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
      // Do some network request
      // on completion call
      [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"theIdentifierUsedInStoryboard" sender:self];
    }
```